# PyCharm : TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, > not NoneType

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pycharm

[image]

Hi All,

I have newly installed PyCharm on my system and while installing any package like numpy or OpenCV-python.

> TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer,
>   not NoneType

But I am able to install the same with command prompt with Pipe install numpy

Python install on below location at my machine

> C:\Program Files\Python38

I really appreciate if somebody please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Did you make any progress? I also have this issue with numpy.